# Extracting substring from string in Python

Tags: python, string, substring

I have a string that looks like this:

```
catString = randomtextrandomtext (cats:1)=1 randomtext randomtextrandomtext (cats:3)=3 randomtext randomtext (cats:1540)=1,540 randomtextrandomtext randomtext (cats:85):85 randomtext
```

I want to print out a string that looks like this:

```
(cats:1)(cats:3)(cats:1540)(cats:85)
```

I tried doing:

```
catCount = ''

for a in catString:
    for b in line.split():
        if '(cats:' in b:
            catCount += str(part)
print catCount
```

However, that code prints out:

```
(cats:1)=1(cats:3)=3(cats:1540)=1,540(cats:85)=85
```

How can I achieve my desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `str.index` and particularly the *start* parameter.

```
catString = "randomtextrandomtext (cats:1)=1 randomtext randomtextrandomtext (cats:3)=3 randomtext randomtext (cats:1540)=1,540 randomtextrandomtext randomtext (cats:85):85 randomtext"

result = ''
end = -1
try:
    while True:
        start = catString.index('(cats:', end+1)
        end = catString.index(')', start)
        result += catString[start:end+1]

except ValueError:
    pass

print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

''.join(re.findall(r'\(cats:\d*\)', catString))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> ''.join(re.findall('\(cats:[0-9]+\)',catString)) 
'(cats:1)(cats:3)(cats:1540)(cats:85)'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this once

```
catCount = ''

for a in catString:
    for b in line.split():
        if '(cats:' in b:
            catCount += str(b[0,b.index(")")+1])
print catCount
```